# Sort output from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sorting

Query1(by combining table1, table 2): returns

```
SELECT t1.ID1,t1.Name
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t1.ID1=t2.ID;

ID1  Name

4      ppp
1      pqr
2      abc
3      xyz
```

Query2(using table 3, which stores IDs): returns

```
select ID from table3;

ID 
1
2
3
4
```

Combine Query1 & Query 2 & produce output as

```
ID Name

1  pqr
2  abc
3  xyz
4  ppp
```

ie main values are coming from 2 different values while sorted values(IDs) are stored in random order in third table.

Comment: So you want the output sorted on what criteria?  If you want it only sorted by ID, just add `ORDER BY id` to your first query, and forget bout table3 entirely.

Comment: @Flimzy ostensibly you only need the values corresponding to those that appear in a separate table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like:-

```
select t1.ID1,t1.Name from table1 t1, table2 t2 
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.ID = t1.ID where t1.ID=t2.ID;
```